# Which data type is best used when programming an optimization problem in C++?

Tags: optimization, cplex, c++

Switching over from CPLEX Optimization Studio, now I want to solve problems in C++ using the CPLEX API.

Being used to the CPLEX data types, I was wondering how they best translate to C++.

For example, using string arrays in CPLEX, what's the best way to represent them in C++?
A vector? pointer?

Maybe there exists some kind of guide for this?

Comment: Don't know what is your C++ background, but I would stick to simple data structures for now, and incrementaly increasing the complexities of my data types. Thus, I would suggest to take the std datastructures initially, and, case you wanna go one step forward, you can use the range c++ lib (https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html), for integrating it with c++20 check https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/issues/1792#event-10061937304

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no definitive answer and it depends on:

- your background
- the nature / characteristic of your problem
- the nature / characteristic of your implementation (proof of concept; deployed software)

As CPLEX' types basically behave like *smart pointers* you are very flexible as this works well with most well-designed libraries.

I'm one of those people dropping all those CPLEX provided containers (don't like them) and the following 3 categories of types / containers dominate all my c++-based modelling-code:

#### My go-to categories of types

##### STL Containers / Algorithms

- Already mentioned in comments
- Typically:

  - vector, set/map, ...
- Also compatible ones: boost containers, google's abseil, ...

##### Eigen ([Link](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page))

- "Eigen is a C++ template library for linear algebra: matrices, vectors, numerical solvers, and related algorithms."

##### boost::graph ([Link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html))

- "A generic interface for traversing graphs, using C++ templates."

##### Detail: STL

Most C++ programmers are very familiar with STL containers and it's a good idea to use them.

At some point, those might not be enough howewer and some alternatives might become interesting:

- e.g. matrices (vector of vector is ugly, inefficient and usage is sub-optimal) or graphs.

##### Disclaimer: Eigen + boost::graph

Eigen as well as boost::graph are state of the art battle-tested libraries i highly recommend.

Both howewer have some learning-curve.

Both are header-only libs which make integration / building much easier.

#### Detail: Eigen

**If my model has (dense) vectors, matrices or tensors, it's likely that i'm using Eigen** (limited to it's containers and related functionality; it offers much more we don't need).

It basically allows everything what people also do in [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html) (python):

- row/col-indexing
- fancy-indexing by vectors
- ...

The docs for the parts most interesting for us: [Eigen: Slicing and Indexing](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html)

Some example of row/col-based indexing typically happening in assignment-like subproblems.

```cpp
using MatrixVar = Eigen::Array<IloNumVar, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>;
using MatrixSol = Eigen::Array<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>;

MatrixVar pos_class_mat(n_sequence, n_classes);

// create variables
for(uint64_t s=0; s<n_sequence; ++s) {
  for(uint64_t c=0; c<n_classes; ++c) {
    pos_class_mat(s, c) = IloNumVar(env, 0, 1, ILOBOOL);
  }
} 

// exactly one classes chosen at each sequence-pos
for(uint64_t s=0; s<n_sequence; ++s) {
  IloExpr expr(env);
  for(auto& var : pos_class_mat(s, Eigen::all))
    expr += var;
  this->model.add(expr == 1);
}
```

In modern C++ we could also do nice things like:

```cpp
static auto get_sol(const MatrixVar& matrix, IloCplex& cplex) {
  auto extract = [&matrix, &cplex] (Eigen::Index i) { return cplex.getValue(matrix(i)); };
  return MatrixSol::NullaryExpr(matrix.rows(), matrix.cols(), extract);
}
```

This allows us to easily print it:

```
std::cout << get_sol(pos_class_mat, cplex) << std::endl;
```

#### Detail: boost::graph

**If my model has a graph-based structure i always use boost::graph which allows some powerful stuff.**

**I'm then able to structure the variable- and constraint objects.**

A somewhat **convoluted example** trying to hint why this might be a good idea
-> handle complexity!.

Here the code does not use CPLEX, but SCIP, but it does not matter. The concept is the same. Only the *handles* for variables and constraints would be different (and i'm lazy).

##### Graphs-setup

We have a global-graph and many local-graphs with some implicit linking.

Think "decomposition".

The goal is to have **a single model** allowing to be reused for:

- greedy-algorithms

  - solve first n parts only
  - solve first n+1 parts only but fix decision of first n parts
  - ...
- large-neighborhood search

  - free some small ratio of decisions of some solution and resolve

just by using this structure (fixed or non-fixed variables).

```
// either a variable yet to be optimized or fixed (e.g. partially-fixed problem or full-fixed solution)
using MaybeContVar = std::variant<std::monostate, SCIP_VAR*, double>;
using MaybeUintVar = std::variant<std::monostate, SCIP_VAR*, uint64_t>;
using MaybeBoolVar = std::variant<std::monostate, SCIP_VAR*, bool>;

struct GlobalGraphNodeParameters {
  std::optional<uint64_t> capacity;
};

struct GlobalGraphNodeVariables {
  
};

struct GlobalGraphNodeConstraints {
  SCIP_CONS* capacity_bound_in;
  SCIP_CONS* capacity_bound_out;
};

struct GlobalGraphNode {
  GlobalGraphNodeParameters parameters;
  GlobalGraphNodeVariables variables;
  GlobalGraphNodeConstraints constraints;
};

// -----

struct GlobalGraphArcParameters {
  bool is_integral;
  boost::dynamic_bitset<> colors;
  std::optional<uint64_t> capacity;
  double cost_fixed;
  double cost_dynamic;
};

struct GlobalGraphArcVariables {
  MaybeBoolVar is_open_negated;
  MaybeContVar is_open;
};

struct GlobalGraphArcConstraints {
  SCIP_CONS* var_bool_open_neg_link;
  SCIP_CONS* capacity_bound_shared;
};

struct GlobalGraphArc {
  uint64_t id;

  GlobalGraphArcParameters parameters;
  GlobalGraphArcVariables variables;
  GlobalGraphArcConstraints constraints;
};

using GlobalGraph = boost::adjacency_list<
  boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS,
  GlobalGraphNode,
  GlobalGraphArc>;

// --------------------

struct LocalGraphNodeParameters {
  // positive -> can send at most
  // negative -> must receive at least
  int64_t flow_imbalance_capacity;
};

struct LocalGraphNodeVariables {
};

struct LocalGraphNodeConstraints {
  SCIP_CONS* flow_conservation_generalized;
};

struct LocalGraphNode {
  bool is_valid;

  LocalGraphNodeParameters parameters;
  LocalGraphNodeVariables variables;
  LocalGraphNodeConstraints constraints;
};

// -----

struct LocalGraphArcParameters {
  double cost_dynamic;
  std::optional<uint64_t> capacity;
};

struct LocalGraphArcVariables {
  MaybeContVar flow;
};

struct LocalGraphArcConstraints {
  SCIP_CONS* openess_indicator;
};

struct LocalGraphArc {
  uint64_t id;

  LocalGraphArcParameters parameters;
  LocalGraphArcVariables variables;
  LocalGraphArcConstraints constraints;
};

// -----

struct LocalGraphAuxParameters {
  std::optional<double> penalized_unperformed_allowed;
};

struct LocalGraphAuxVariables {
  MaybeBoolVar is_unperformed;
};

struct LocalGraphAuxConstraints {
};

struct LocalGraphAux {
  LocalGraphAuxParameters parameters;
  LocalGraphAuxVariables variables;
  LocalGraphAuxConstraints constraints;
};

using LocalGraph = boost::adjacency_list<
  boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS,
  LocalGraphNode,
  LocalGraphArc,
  LocalGraphAux>;

// Link global and local graph (decomposed parts) together

struct Model {
  GlobalGraph global_graph;
  std::vector<std::optional<LocalGraph>> local_graphs;
};
```

##### Example usage

Then we could do cool things like:

```cpp
  auto es = boost::edges(lgraph);
  for(auto eit = es.first; eit != es.second; ++eit) {
    auto l_source_vertex = boost::source(*eit, lgraph); 
    
    auto edge_in_global_graph_opt = get_specific_arc_incident(problem.global_graph, l_source_vertex, lgraph[*eit].id);
    assert(edge_in_global_graph_opt.has_value());

    auto& props = lgraph[*eit];
    auto& props_in_global = problem.global_graph[edge_in_global_graph_opt.value()];

    double flow_var_capacity = props.parameters.capacity.value_or(SCIPinfinity(scip));
    double cost_dynamic = props.parameters.cost_dynamic;

    // flow
    if(std::holds_alternative<SCIP_VAR*>(props.variables.flow)) {
      // unfixed
      if(props_in_global.parameters.is_integral)
        SCIPcreateVar(scip, &std::get<SCIP_VAR*>(props.variables.flow), "flow", 0.0, flow_var_capacity, cost_dynamic, SCIP_VARTYPE_INTEGER, TRUE, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
      else
        SCIPcreateVar(scip, &std::get<SCIP_VAR*>(props.variables.flow), "flow", 0.0, flow_var_capacity, cost_dynamic, SCIP_VARTYPE_CONTINUOUS, TRUE, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
      SCIPaddVar(scip, std::get<SCIP_VAR*>(props.variables.flow));  
    }
    else if(std::holds_alternative<double>(props.variables.flow)) {
      // fixed
      double fixed_value = std::get<double>(props.variables.flow);
      props.variables.flow = MaybeContVar(std::in_place_type<SCIP_VAR*>);

      if(props_in_global.parameters.is_integral)
        SCIPcreateVar(scip, &std::get<SCIP_VAR*>(props.variables.flow), "flow", 0.0, flow_var_capacity, cost_dynamic, SCIP_VARTYPE_INTEGER, TRUE, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
      else
        SCIPcreateVar(scip, &std::get<SCIP_VAR*>(props.variables.flow), "flow", 0.0, flow_var_capacity, cost_dynamic, SCIP_VARTYPE_CONTINUOUS, TRUE, FALSE, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
      SCIPaddVar(scip, std::get<SCIP_VAR*>(props.variables.flow));
      SCIP_Bool infeasible;
      SCIP_Bool fixed;
      SCIPfixVar(scip, std::get<SCIP_VAR*>(props.variables.flow), fixed_value, &infeasible, &fixed);     
    }
```

and also a minimal large-neighborhood search (changing fixed/sol -> unfixed/var for some parts):

```cpp
void Lns::parameterize_unstructured() {
  // Lets keep it sample -> randomize each decision
  std::bernoulli_distribution p_unfix(options.lns_unfix_probability);

  // global
  {
    // GlobalGraphArcVariables
    auto es = boost::edges(working_model.global_graph);
    for (auto eit = es.first; eit != es.second; ++eit) {
      if(p_unfix(prng))
        working_model.global_graph[*eit].variables = GlobalGraphArcVariables {
          .is_open_negated = MaybeBoolVar(std::in_place_type<SCIP_VAR*>),
          .is_open = MaybeContVar(std::in_place_type<SCIP_VAR*>)
        };
    }
  }

  // local
  for(auto& lgraph_opt : working_model.local_graphs) {
    assert(lgraph_opt.has_value());

    // LocalGraphAuxVariables
    if(p_unfix(prng))
      lgraph_opt.value()[boost::graph_bundle].variables = LocalGraphAuxVariables {
        .is_unperformed = MaybeBoolVar(std::in_place_type<SCIP_VAR*>)
      };

    // LocalGraphArcVariables
    auto es = boost::edges(lgraph_opt.value());
    for (auto eit = es.first; eit != es.second; ++eit) {
      if(p_unfix(prng))
        lgraph_opt.value()[*eit].variables = LocalGraphArcVariables {
          .flow = MaybeContVar(std::in_place_type<SCIP_VAR*>)
        };
    }
  }
}
```

#### Summary / Recommendations

- Don't be scared not to use the provided types (`IloNumArray` and co.)

  - If: stick to well-established alternatives (STL; maybe Eigen, boost::graph and co.)

    - Much larger community to help you out (usage is orthogonal to optimization and even non-optimization people can help)
    - You can reuse concepts easily when changing the solver

      - CPLEX, Gurobi, SCIP, CoinOR Cbc, ... It's just a different *handle-type* within your containers
  - Fun fact: Using python, i'm also using `numpy` / `networkx` quite frequently, despite the availability of high-lvl Python-based modelling-APIs (e.g. docplex)
- Pick what's working for you

  - If you cannot invest the time to get ready for Eigen/boost::graph (both metaprogramming-heavy), it's probably not worth it
- Ask yourself why you are using C++ and how you should make the best out of it

  - Some do it because of performance (e.g. compared to python; only matters for model-setup)
  - I mostly do it because of all those C++ capabilities

    - Strong type-system, metaprogramming
    - Also:

      - Availability of high-quality libraries
  - Meaning: Small POCs won't always be C++-based and for sure won't look like above graph example

    - But at some point investing into the core-design helps to limit error-finding later!

Comment: Wow, thanks for that in-depth write up! I'll check out the libraries you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at the C++ source code examples that ship with CPLEX Optimization Studio. Then have a look at the documentation for the C++ API, specifically for the optim.concert group. You'll find built in support for a lot of array types.